# mySQL and express throwing error with working query

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am getting an error when trying to send data from express to mysql. The query itself works fine when ran in mysql, but throws a syntax error in express. Here is the error

```js
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO accounts (strPassword) VALUES ('$2a$12$UA.y6cWYV6r0mXiYYi0iQuNBtZzit' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "BEGIN; INSERT INTO accounts (strPassword) VALUES ('$2a$12$UA.y6cWYV6r0mXiYYi0iQuNBtZzit4jQPJ2pt8P7od6VPnhjTuC3O'); INSERT 
INTO accountdetails (intAccountID, strUserName, dtmDOB, strEmail, strIGN) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'test3', '1994-3-4', 'test3@test.com' ,'test3'); COMMIT;"
```

Other queries work fine o

Comment: I have not use `node.js` or `express`, what is `BEGIN` supposed to be doing? In MySQL,it is only used to mark the begin of code blocks in procedures and functions (and paired with a corresponding `END`); and is not really valid in queries or scripts. Also, many libraries do not allow multiple statements in one "execute".

Comment: I need to insert the username and password into the accounts table, and the rest of the data into the accountdetails table. In order to do so, I need to get the last_insert_id to link the records on the intAccountID PK. The BEGIN is supposed to allow me to run multiple statements in one go. In mysql this functions properly.

Comment: MySQL (Workbench), and many other interfaces allow multiple statements without BEGIN END in scripts and query tabs. last_insert_id() does not require BEGIN/END or transactions to use, it is session/connection specific.